# Delphi - Byte array to string

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, byte

In my Delphi VCL Form application I've a procedure which has a TBuff parameter (defined before as **array of byte**). Inside this procedure, I have to convert the parameter to a string.

```
procedure Form1.Convert(Collect: TBuff);
var 
   str: String;
begin
   str := SysUtils.StringOf(Collect);
end;
```

After the compile, I was warned about the presence of this compiler error:

> Incompatible types :'System.TArray<System.TByte>' and 'TBuff'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem that you encounter is that you have defined your own byte array type like this:

```
type
  TBuff = array of Byte;
```

This private type of yours is not assignment compatible with other byte array types. Most RTL functions that use byte arrays use the RTL type `TBytes` which is declared as `TArray<Byte>`.

The first thing for you to do is to remove `TBuff` from your program and instead use `TBytes`. If you continue to use `TBuff` you will find that all your byte array code lives in its own ghetto, unable to interact with library functionality that uses `TBytes`. So, escape the ghetto, and remove your `TBuff` type from existence.

Now, in order to convert a byte array to a string, you need to provide encoding information to do this. You have selected `StringOf` which should be considered a legacy function these days. It is better to be more explicit in your conversion and use `TEncoding`.

For instance, if the byte array is UTF-8 you write:

```
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ByteArray);
```

If the byte array is encoded in the local ANSI encoding you write:

```
str := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(ByteArray);
```

In your case the use of `StringOf` indicates that the byte array is ANSI encoded so this latter example is what you need.

Comment: Just a note that Delphi XE2 added the .ANSI property to TEncoding that you can use instead of .Default (which now returns UTF8 if you are on Mac OSX.)  In cases where I know the byte array is ANSI I've switch to using the .ANSI property to be more explicit (and also in case they decide to change the default meaning.)

Comment: @MarkF they won't change the meaning of Default, but the code is better written explicitly as you suggest. I changed it. Thanks.